# Unable to install beaver cause mosquitto is not found (debian Jessie)

Tags: debian, mosquitto, beaver

Since this morning a cannot install beaver (36.0.1 nor 36.1.0) using :

```
pip install beaver==36.0.1
```

The error is the following :

```
failed: [etg-log-tmp] => {"cmd": "/usr/bin/pip install beaver==36.0.1", "failed": true}
msg: stdout: Downloading/unpacking beaver==36.0.1
Downloading/unpacking conf-d>=0.0.4 (from beaver==36.0.1)
  Downloading conf_d-0.0.4.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-Y21cqz/conf-d/setup.py) egg_info for package conf-d

Downloading/unpacking kafka-python==0.9.5 (from beaver==36.0.1)
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-Y21cqz/kafka-python/setup.py) egg_info for package kafka-python

Downloading/unpacking python-daemon>=1.5.2,<=1.6.1 (from beaver==36.0.1)
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-Y21cqz/python-daemon/setup.py) egg_info for package python-daemon

Downloading/unpacking glob2==0.3 (from beaver==36.0.1)
  Downloading glob2-0.3.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-Y21cqz/glob2/setup.py) egg_info for package glob2

Downloading/unpacking pika>=0.9.14 (from beaver==36.0.1)
Downloading/unpacking msgpack-pure>=0.1.3 (from beaver==36.0.1)
  Downloading msgpack-pure-0.1.3.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-Y21cqz/msgpack-pure/setup.py) egg_info for package msgpack-pure

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): boto>=2.18.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from beaver==36.0.1)
Downloading/unpacking redis>=2.7.5 (from beaver==36.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from beaver==36.0.1)
Downloading/unpacking mosquitto>=1.1 (from beaver==36.0.1)
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement mosquitto>=1.1 (from beaver==36.0.1)
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for mosquitto>=1.1 (from beaver==36.0.1)
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

JM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: a new pip package has been released (36.2.0). If you're like me and use the chef beaver recipe you have to configure it to explicitly use 36.2.0 and over.

Alternatively: this has been fixed on master, for now you can use `pip install git+git://github.com/python-beaver/python-beaver.git@master#egg=beaver` until the pip package is updated.

Comment: OK. Many thank's for your help. Unfortunately we will not be able to checkout from github for security reason so we will have to wait the official pip package. Can you explain me what happens to the Mosquitto package ?

Comment: The mosquitto package was unceremoniously deleted from pip, after it had been replaced (since 2013!) with paho-mqtt.

Comment: For information, there is now a 36.2.0 which is OK !